# XP clients on sbs network have limited or zero access to specific websites, win 7 ok

Tags: windows, networking, website

Could anyone shed some light on access to some websites from XP pc's on our network.

For a few weeks now browsers on the XP machines either can't or have very limited access to some websites. Win 7 access is fine, as are XP pc's connected directly to the broadband router. So the issue must be between the XP box and the server?

I've run MS network monitor, but being a novice it doesn't really help me. I can see the request start, and then the server timeout, but no clues as to why.. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be very helpful !

Other details.. sbs 2011, sharedband ISP with bonded lines..

Windows XP IP Configuration

```
    Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : MAN06
    Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : linwave.local
    Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
    IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
    DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : linwave.local
                                        linwave.local

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : linwave.local
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82562V-2 10/100 Network Connection
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1D-09-7A-A9-82
    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.20.65
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.20.10
    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.20.11
    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.20.11
    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 14 January 2015 14:08:41
    Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 22 January 2015 14:08:41
```

win7

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DES14
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : linwave.local
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : linwave.local

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : linwave.local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 54-04-A6-DA-5C-8C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::dc9d:a28f:1252:66fc%11(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.20.38(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 15 January 2015 07:13:22
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 23 January 2015 07:13:22
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.20.10
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.20.11
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 240387238
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-36-60-8B-54-04-A6-DA-5C-8C
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.20.11
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.linwave.local:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : linwave.local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: We miss detail, please run an ipconfig /all from both a XP and Win7 and post the result

Answer (score 1):

SBS--at least, SBS08--comes with some default policies for XP and Vista that detect the OS via WMI.  It's hard to say based on your question, but my suspicion is that something is misfiring in one of these policies (perhaps a conflict with another policy?).

Comment: Ok, but how would I go about checking for conflicts of this sort ?

Comment: I'd start with gpresult and rsop.